# how to retrieve or get individual values or points of a svg path in d3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js, path, coordinates

Let us say for example , I have the following svg path in d3.js. All I want is to retrieve or store individual values of each point in the path separately using d3.  js

```
var p = d3.select("body").select("g").attr("d","M"407,233 "L"505,233);
```

Here I want to retrieve and store the path values 407,233,505.6 and 233.6 separately.I tried my best but couldn't get the desired result. This question is different from other similar type questions asked before. My question specifically deals with d3.js and not plain javascript or jquery. Please help me

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, what's your use case?  You are selecting on `d`?  What?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You'll probably have to use regex to do it

Comment: @lan  Sir please elaborate . I am working on a project that require me to select individual elements of a path.

Comment: I don't think d3 is going to do this for you: It's a library to take data you already have an bind it to the DOM, rather than extract data from SVG already in the DOM. Would something like this do instead: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/m8x35jkc/

Comment: @Henry S  Thank you Sir... for your timely help...! Thank you very much.